# run for -loop to new linkedlist c#

Tags: c#, object, linked-list

I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it in English.

I can give the example like:

I key in 3 and execute a for-loop to new 3 linkedlist.

but how?

```
int a = 3;
for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)              
{                     
     LinkedList<String> LinkList1 = new LinkedList<String>();          
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code you've tried?

Comment: you can explain with some piece of code.

Comment: That is not clear at all. Did you try google translate from your native language?

Comment: i post my code. I want to new LinkedList as much as the number I put in

Comment: It still doesnt make any sense to me yet...

Comment: whats wrong with your code? Did you get any error?

Comment: You want to create a new linked list each iteration of your loop?

Comment: @Sam check my answer, does it what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clearly don't under stand what you want to ask.If you want for-loop in `linkedlist` You got a basic operation and for-loop example of linkedlist here.
[linkedlist example](http://www.functionx.com/csharp1/examples/linkedlist.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but;

```
int a = 3;            

List<LinkedList<string>> listOfLinkedLists = new List<LinkedList<string>>();            

for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
{
    listOfLinkedLists.Add(new LinkedList<string>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create 3 linked lists...Right?

So best ways is to create a array of list.

```
        int i = 3;
        List<String>[] listArray = new List<string>[i];
```